# Scrape data from NCBI books section?

Tags: python, text-mining, biopython, ncbi

I'm currently writing a program which requires me to scrape articles from the NCBI.

I'm using the Entrez Utilities to do this (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25497/).

I have figured out how to do this with PubMed data, namely by using `handle = Entrez.efetch(db='pubmed', id=pmid, retmode='text', rettype='abstract')`.

However, I want to scrape data from the books section of the NCBI because the pubmed section contains incomplete articles (compare for example https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/20301533/ vs https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK1359/).

I have a list of all the GeneReviews ID's (e.g NB1359, NB1400 etc.) in a text file but I'm not sure how to go about scraping this data because `handle = Entrez.esearch(db='books', term="NB1359", retmode='text')` does not return the text in the article.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way of doing it with `Entrez.esearch` either, but I would just download the printable version of the page and parse that directly:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

genereview_ids = ['NBK1359', 'NBK1400']

for genereview_id in genereview_ids:
  url = f"https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/{genereview_id}/?report=printable"
  r = requests.get(url)
  html_doc = r.text
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
  print(soup.find('meta', {'name': 'description'})['content'])
```

Output:

```
The purpose of this overview is to increase the awareness of clinicians regarding congenital diaphragmatic hernia and its genetic causes and management.
Cystinosis comprises three allelic phenotypes:
```